# Using Compiler Optimization in Calculating Speed-up

Tags: gcc, cuda, gpu, compiler-optimization, nvcc

When we are talking about a parallel program in Cuda on GPU having a speed up over a similar sequential one on CPU , should the sequential one be compiled by a Compiler Optimizer (gcc -O2)?

I have paralleled a program on GPU. It has a speed up of 18 in comparison with its CPU implementation without a compiler optimizer. But when I add the option -O2 to nvcc compiler, the speed up rate decreases to 8.

Comment: The CUDA compiler  uses full compiler optimisations by default. You are probably *reducing* the degree of compilation optimization by select `O2`.

Comment: @talonmies You should convert this comment to an answer. Perhaps this would give more immediate help to other users with similar questions. From this comment, I would say that the sequential code should be compiled with full optimization options to make a fair comparison, right? So, if the user is currently not applying any compiler optimization to the sequential code, the speed-up is perhaps less than `18`.

Comment: In addition to the compiler options, a parallel version in CPU using OpenMP would be a worthier comparison. Most of the new computers have multithreading and most of the code suitable for CUDA can be easily parallelized with a few OpenMP directives. Therefore, you will be comparing your CUDA program with the best version in CPU.

Comment: Speedups are compared by enabling maximum possible optimization by the compiler. In general -O3 should be sufficient. Sometimes highly optimized code is not possible just by passing -O3, you have to pass additional flags (to enable optimizations disabled by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course optimizer should be used for both GPU and CPU program when comparing the performance.

If your focus on GPU v.s. CPU, the comparison should not be affected by the quality of the software code. We often assume the code should have the best performance on its hardware.